# Change default JSON Serializer

Tags: asp.net, web-services

ASP.NET default json serializer is slow, and I need a lot of performance, so I want to use [ServiceStack.Text Serializer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text), is there a way I can use that serializer instead of the one by default?

If I send a JSON request to my ASMX file, and return an object it will serialize it using Microsoft's slow implementation.

I guess I could always return a string, and serialize manually, but I just want to know if it's possible.

Comment: Take a look at this first: http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/

Comment: The problem is that when you return an object, microsoft's serializer is slow. Very slow.

Comment: if you look at the web method implementation in the article provided by  Leniel Macaferi, you will find one approach is to return string and you can definitely use other serializer for this.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb763183%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Basically you need to put your custom converter in configuration tag on web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50">
          <converters>
            <add name="MyCustomConverter" 
              type="MyCompany.ConvertersNameSpace.MyTypeConverter"/>
          </converters>
        </jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

Since JavascriptSerializer needs to inform which classes are supported, i think asp.net will assume your serializer instead of default serializer.

Comment: Your converter must derive from [`JavaScriptConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter).